# Is there a way to draw a connecting line between different UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cgpath

Let's say that I have an UITableView (but it might as well be with an UICollectionView) and N rows (cells).
I want to draw a path that starts at the center of the first cell and that goes to the center of the next cell +/- a certain offset on the horizontal axis. 
Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: I can't think of any easy way of doing this, other than adding a view above the table view.

Comment: If you just want to draw a line that might even be doable with an image in the background, which might be weird and not even easier. So I agree with @LordZsolt.